# How to select last published comment created by student?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    FirstName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BirthDate datetime NOT NULL,
    IndexNumber nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ParentName nvarchar(50) NULL,
    Gender char(1) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Students PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE StudentComments
(
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    Comment text NOT NULL,
    StudentId int NOT NULL,
    InsertAt datetime NOT NULL,
    IsPublished bit NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StudentComments PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_StudentComments_Students FOREIGN KEY (StudentId) REFERENCES Students (Id)
)
```

My task is to select Students.Id, Students.FirstName, Students.LastName, StudentComments.Comment, StudentComments.InsertAt for last published comment of each student.

I need to do this by using only one select command (not nested queries).

My attempted Query:

```
 SELECT s.Id,
       (s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName) AS Name,
       sc.Comment,
       sc.InsertAt,
       MAX(sc.InsertAt) AS NewestDate
 FROM Students AS s
 INNER JOIN StudentComments sc
  ON s.Id = sc.StudentsId AND sc.IsPublished = 1 
 GROUP BY /* Here is problem - I'm Begginer */
  HAVING sc.InsertAt = MAX(scInsertAt);
```

Comment: Great.  What have you tried?

Comment: Yet another nice Quiz question!

Comment: I have tried: SELECT s.Id, (s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName) AS Name, sc.Comment, sc.InsertAt, MAX(sc.InsertAt) AS NewestDate FROM Students AS s INNER JOIN StudentComments sc ON s.Id = sc.StudentsId AND sc.IsPublished = 1 GROUP BY /* Here is problem - I'm Beginner */ HAVING sc.InsertAt = MAX(scInsertAt);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of following solutions:

```
SELECT  src.Id, src.FirstName, src.LastName, src.Comment, src.InsertAt
FROM 
(
    SELECT  s.Id, s.FirstName, s.LastName, sc.Comment, sc.InsertAt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sc.StudentId ORDER BY sc.InsertAt DESC) RowNum
    FROM    dbo.Students s INNER JOIN dbo.StudentComments sc ON s.Id = sc.StudentId
    --WHERE sc.IsPublished = 1
) src
WHERE   src.RowNum = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT  s.Id, s.FirstName, s.LastName, lc.Comment, lc.InsertAt
FROM    dbo.Students s 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  TOP(1) sc.Comment, sc.InsertAt
    FROM    dbo.StudentComments sc 
    WHERE   s.Id = sc.StudentId
    --AND       sc.IsPublished = 1
    ORDER BY sc.InsertAt DESC
) lc; -- Last comment
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery:

```
SELECT Students.Id, Students.FirstName, Students.LastName,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Comment from StudentComments WHERE StudentID = Students.ID ORDER BY InsertAt DESC) as Comment,
        (SELECT TOP 1 InsertAt from StudentComments WHERE StudentID = Students.ID ORDER BY InsertAt DESC) as InsertAt
FROM Students
```

Comment: And I think that here is needed sub-query, but my professor asked me to do that without it.

Comment: Ah, I see!  In that case, Bogdan's answer will work.  Or you could do a group by and a join, but that would be uglier.